# MySQL query adding ' to variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql

A MySQL query that I am running is throwing up the following error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'desc = 'Enter Description Here'' at line 2

The desc is a variable '$desc' the error suggests that there is an extra ' before desc but there is nothing in the code (below) if I remove desc altogether it works fine (obviously not updating that part) its very strange, your help is greatly appreciated :-)

The code is

```
//Get the form data
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $keywords = $_POST['keywords'];
    $desc = $_POST['desc'];



//initialise connection with databse

require_once('../Connections/EliteGrooming.php');
mysql_select_db($database_EliteGrooming, $EliteGrooming);

//Execute the query

mysql_real_escape_string($title, $keywords, $desc);

$query = "
    UPDATE site_settings
    SET site_title = '$title', keywords = '$keywords', desc = '$desc';";

mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_close();
header('Location: ../admin/site-settings.php?updated');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`desc` is a **[reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)**, you must escaped it with backtick

```
$query = "
    UPDATE site_settings
    SET site_title = '$title', keywords = '$keywords', `desc` = '$desc';";
```

but your query is vulnerable with `SQL Injection`, please read the article below,

- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: Thank you for your help, it worked great! I added mysql_real_escape_string($title, $keywords, $desc); does this not prevent against SQL injection? again thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @JamesLeist [SQL injection that gets around mysql_real_escape_string()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5741264/491243)

Comment: @JamesLeist you are always welcome :D

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape [reserved words in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) like `desc` with backticks

```
UPDATE site_settings
SET site_title = '$title', keywords = '$keywords', `desc` = '$desc';";
```